# TFS Migration from 2012 & 2017 to 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration

We have to upgrade TFS version from 2012 to 2017. The problem we are facing is we have some team projects in TFS 2017 lower environment and some team projects are in 2012 production instance. We want to migrate 2012 team projects and 2017 team projects to a new TFS 2017 production instance under one team project collection. We need some help in defining the upgrade/migration strategy keeping this scenario in consideration.  Please let us know if someone can lend help.

Comment: There are many ways to skin this cat: you should be more specific or hire one of the many consultants around the world to evaluate your needs and suggest the best solution for your organization.

Answer (score 3):

It supports to move collections from TFS 2012 to TFS 2017 directly follow the [move collection document](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-project-collection). You don't need to upgrade your TFS 2012 to TFS 2017 first. It does the upgrading When it attaches to the new TFS instance, just follow theses steps:

1. Detach the collection
2. Back up the collection database
3. Move the collection database
4. Attach the collection
5. [Configure Features for team projects(option)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/customize/configure-features-after-upgrade)

**Note**: The step5 is done when you move TFS 2012 collection. If you move TFS 2017 collection to your new TFS 2017. This step doesn't need to do.

And you want these 2 collection to merge to one collection totally. This is not support currently. There are two many conflicts: changeset numbers, work item IDs, builds,etc. And it also doesn't support to move team project from one collection to another. Here is a [user voice about move team projects between collections](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te) which has many votes already:

> We still plan to evaluate picking this work up and possibly getting it into the following next major release. We’ll provide an update once a decision has been reached.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you do the migration from TFS2012 to TFS2017 just as described by [Microsoft here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/upgrade/get-started) and after your new TFS2017 is up and running, move the Team Project Collections from your current TFS2017 to the new one which is [described here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/move-project-collection)