# Upgrading TFS 2012 to 2017

Tags: tfs

I'm looking to upgrade TFS. I've been reading up on how to do this. I'm not doing an in place upgrade. I have 1 server with TFS 2012 and another with TFS 2017. All we use is source control. Nothing else so it's pretty basic. We only have a couple of projects as well.

From what I'm reading you detach the project collection from the old. Backup the collection database from the old. Restore this to the new and then attach that project collection to the new.

This sounds like it moves it. How is a simple "copy" done instead of a move? The idea being I'd like to test this out which means I would prefer minimal workings interruption with the current production TFS 2012 collections. After I detach from TFS 2012 and have done the backup to get that over to the TFS 2017 server, should it be just a simple attach to get it attached again on tfs 2012 so devs can keep working?

Also, I assume before a detach everyone should have everything checked in or does that not matter what state it's in when I detach a collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you cannot simply "Copy" TFS from one hardware to another such as copy files.

In your scenario you want to manage the projects/files in source control, that means you need keep the source control history (changesets, commits etc). And the information is recorded in Databases. So, you need to do actions against the databases.

The simplest way for you is [Moving team project collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-project-collection?view=tfs-2015&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) from TFS 2012 to 2017, actually it's an "Copy" action, the previous TFS 2012 is still available.  See this similar thread : [TFS Migration from 2012 & 2017 to 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064379/tfs-migration-from-2012-2017-to-2017)

If you want to keep everything in TFS 2017, then you need to have everything checked in first before a detach.

Another way is [Move or Clone Team Foundation Server from one hardware to another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/move-clone-hardware?view=tfs-2015#install-config-sql-svr-data-tier), but it requires that you must install the same SQL server version and edition that you used previous (TFS 2012), then upgrade from TFS 2012 to TFS 2017 in place. (You can reference this article : [Upgrading from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rob/2016/12/22/upgrading-from-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2017/))

Comment: Are you sure that a full checkin is required. I have never set that as a requirement when moving from server to server. As long as the collection ID is unchanged then I would say that checkouts etc. will just continue as is on the new server.

Comment: Yes, sorry when I said copy vs move it was already in the context of detaching, make db backup, copy the backup to the other server and restoring, then attaching again. But the detaching from the original is the part that has me nervous because if something goes wrong and I can't reattach to the same DB (because I just wanted a test for the other new version) that would be a bad situation. So was hoping for a less invasive way to do it but seems there really isn't. Seems like you must detach first from existing TFS.

Comment: @ToreØstergaard I just tried it while having files checked out and everything worked fine when I moved the collection to a new server. So you are correct.